# is DSL, Cable internet, or AT&T U-verse better for a home office?

Tags: internet

what ISP should I use for home and work?

the options I see are:  (assuming about $39 to $50 a month.  $70 max)

Comcast: FAST, 15Mbps down and 9Mbps up.  But goes down once every 2 days on average and need to reboot cable modem.

DSL: slow.  3Mbps down and 384kbps up and that's a joke compared to Comcast's 9Mbps up.  But almost never failed for 2 years.

AT&T U-verse fiber optics: 6Mbps down and 1Mbps up.  Seems reliable so far.  Amazing how it can handle digital TV (2 channels of HD, 2 channels of SD), Internet, phone, all at the same time using 1 router!

Verizon: knows nothing about it yet.

Any other options?  I thought of using 2 at the same time but to access files between 2 networks and using SVN seems troublesome.  So maybe I will choose one and settle with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience the quality of home-network providers varies by region.  I doubt anyone can give you a useful answer to this, unless they happen to live in the same place as you do.  You are probably better off asking other people near you.  Perhaps ask on at local linux-user-group mail list.

Answer (score 1):

I have a Comcast business connection, and I'm very happy with it. I've never had to reboot the cable modem in the ~5 years that I've had it. Very fast, very stable. And I have dedicated IP addresses.

Comment: so you have static IP address?  how much does the service monthly fee range from?

Answer (score 1):

I'm in Riverside County, CA and have AT&T UVerse.  The Internet here is great.  Speed is always good, and the uptime is great.  I work from home daily, going into the office maybe once a month at most.

You also get to use the Internet at all Starbucks for free if there is ever an issue.

Comment: how do you get to work at home most of the month?  the boss is ok with it?

Comment: Boss is fine with it.  I work for a small company.  When gas prices started getting really high I told him I would only spent X to get to work.  Eventually that was 2 days a week.  We then realized I could get more done working from home than work, so I just stopped coming in.

Answer (score 0):

Get the one that gives you the best SLA.  Nothing in the consumer line will do that at all, so let that guide you.

Comment: SLA = service level agreement?  what items are there?  you mean such as guaranteed download and upload speed?

Comment: Yes, SLA = service level agreement.  You're looking for things like guaranteed uptime of the connection, not speeds (though that is good too).

Often the difference between a "business" DSL and a home DSL is how much they care if it stops working.